# Native Google Maps API Overview Control

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The Google API has a ['map overview control'](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#OverviewMapControlOptions)  but it is extremely limited in that there are only two options (on/off and positioning). I would like to be able to set the **size** and **zoom level** of the overview map. Is this possible and if so, how?

I found an [external library that does this](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-v3-overviewmapcontrol/downloads/detail?name=jOverviewMapControlV3_rev18.zip) but I would prefer a less clunky native method.

If this cannot be done natively, are there other libraries/methods/hacks out there to do this?